# Hash function for collection of items that disregards ordering

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, hashcode

I am using a the [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) function to get the hash value of my object which contains two integers and two Strings. Moreover, I have a dictionary where I store these objects; the process is that I check if the object exists with the hash value, if yes I update if not I insert the new one.

The thing is that when creating the objects, I do not know the order of the object variables and I want to treat the objects as same no matter the order of these variables.

Is there an alternative function to the `hash()` function that does not consider the order of the variables?

```
#Consequently what I want is:
hash((int1,str1,int2,str2)) == hash((int2,str2,int1,str1))
```

Comment: Would you post a small section of your code to make clearer what you are doing? My first thought is to sort the two integers, but I cannot tell whether this would work in your implementation.

Comment: You can always sort the input: `hash(tuple(sorted((1, 2))))`.

Comment: @TomLynch I showed a toy example, in my code I have also strings so it is difficult to sort.

Comment: Maybe you should modify the question because now it strongly suggest you expect to have there only integers.

Comment: @Eleshar just updated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) instead of a tuple:

```
>>> hash(frozenset([1, 2, 'a', 'b']))
1190978740469805404
>>>
>>> hash(frozenset([1, 'a', 2, 'b']))
1190978740469805404
>>>
>>> hash(frozenset(['a', 2, 'b', 1]))
1190978740469805404
```

However, the removal of duplicates from the iterable presents a subtle problem:

```
>>> hash(frozenset([1,2,1])) == hash(frozenset([1,2,2]))
True
```

---

You can fix this by creating a counter from the iterable using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and calling `frozenset` on the counter's items, thus preserving the count of each item from the original iterable:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> hash(frozenset(Counter([1,2,1]).items())) 
-307001354391131208
>>> hash(frozenset(Counter([1,1,2]).items()))
-307001354391131208
>>> 
>>> hash(frozenset(Counter([1,2,1]).items())) == hash(frozenset(Counter([1,2,2]).items()))
False
```

Comment: it works because there's the same number of elements in each set, so even if there are duplicates it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the observation. It revealed a bug :)

Comment: Not a bug for the OP problem though.

Comment: `FrozenMultiset()` would also solve this duplicates issue https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiset

Comment: @Chris_Rands Good one! A `collections.Counter` object is a multiset. I guess their implementation of the `FrozenMultiset` has some sort of counter underneath. I think you can make the link and some snippet into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually for things like this it helps immeasurably if you post some sample code, but I'll assume you've got something like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))
```

You're taking a hash of a tuple there, which does care about order. If you want your hash to not care about the order of the ints, then just use a [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(frozenset([self.x, self.y]))
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Whoops! I meant frozen sets.

Comment: Considering the comments about also including strings, I think this is the right answer! Define a class, and use that to specify whatever hash method you want.

Comment: @ymbirtt Just upvoted thank you for the effort as well. Apologies for the confusion of not using Strings.

Answer (score 1):

If the range of the values is not too great you could add them together, that way the order can be disregarded, however it does increase the possibility for 2 hashes to have the same value:

```
def hash_list(items):
    value = 0
    for item in items:
        value+= hash(item)
    return value

hash_list(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> 8409777985338339540
hash_list(['b', 'a', 'c'])
>>> 8409777985338339540
```